# How to enforce scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b to use 'dtype=float32'

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gpu, multidimensional-array

I am trying to optimize functions with GPU calculation in Python, so I prefer to store all my data as ndarrays with `dtype=float32`.

When I am using `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`, I notice that the optimizer always passes a `float64` (on my 64bit machine) parameter to my objective and gradient functions, even when I pass a `float32` ndarray as the initial search point `x0`. This is different when I use the cg optimizer `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg`, where when I pass in a float32 array as `x0`, the optimizer will use `float32` in all consequent objective/gradient function invocations.

So my question is: can I enforce `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` to optimize on `float32` parameters like in `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can ever do it. `fmin_l_bfgd_b` is provided not by pure python code, but by a extension (a wrap of FORTRAN code). In Win32/64 platform it can be found at `\scipy\optimize\_lbfgsb.pyd`. What you want may only be possible if you can compile the extension differently or modify the FORTRAN code. If you check that FORTRAN code, it has `double precision` all over the place, which is basically `float64`. I am not sure just changing them all to `single precision` will do the job.

Among the other optimization methods, `cobyla` is also provided by FORTRAN. Powell's methods too.

Comment: Thanks CT Zhu, yeah, I definitely don't want to modify the FORTRAN code to violate the compatibility. One alternative that I can think of is to hijack the parameter control when passing in and out the `fmin_l_bfgs_b` function - so in my objective/gradient function, the passed param value will be casted to `float32`, and when the objective/gradient value is returned, they are explicitly casted to `float64` again. It solves the problem, but I suspect theres a performance penalty - I don't know if the GPU speedup is worth the explict casting overhead.

Comment: Yeah, the brutal force method came to my mind as well. The reason you have to use `l_bfgs_b` is to enable constrains/bounds, right? If that is the case, maybe you can modified your objective somewhat, such as using a Lagrange multiplier, such that your function is naturally bounded/constrained. That way you may be no longer stuck with `l_bfgs_b`. I also wonder if explicit type converting would cancel the benefit of GPU or not. Honestly, I don't have a good feeling about it, but I will be very happy if your result indicates the opposite.

Comment: Most of time I am using it to solve machine learning problems, which are usually unconstrained. L-BFGS and SGD are favorite optimizers in machine learning nowadays as SGD can move to promising area quite fast and L-BFGS will refine the solution. : )

Comment: Thank you for point it out, it is always good to know that is popular in other disciplines. It worth a shot to ask the authors of L-BFGS-B, http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/lbfgsb.html, some small modification to the FORTRAN code may be all way you need. Cheers!